# Strange messages from fsck_hfs

Tags: hard-drive, disk-utility, external-disk, fsck, fsck-hfs

I am trying to check an entire USB external disk that is not erased. For that reason I have typed

```
fsck_hfs -fy -l -S -d /dev/disk1s2
```

This the result

[image]

Several messages I found strange here

1. NO WRITE - how can that be? If I am trying to fix it how can it be no write?
2. ok, it found a bad block at 137228189184 but at end it says the disk is OK
3. what is block 26023808 NO MATCH?
4. at end it says fsmodified = 0??? No modification performed?

I don't understand this. Have fsck_hfs fixed my disk? I by fixed I mean mark the block as unusable or reformatted it or whatever?

Thanks

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The command you have given includes the "-l" option, which means to perform a "test-only check" and that "no repairs can be made". Essentially this means that it won't write to the file system, which explains your questions 1 and 4.

Regarding questions 2 and 3: The disk as such might be "OK" (i.e. usable) from the point of view of the filesystem even though a single bad block has been detected. As you have specified the "-S" option, fsck_hfs will attempt to match the bad block to a file name - it found not match. This could indicate that the bad block does not affect any of your files.

Consider replacing the drive when you start having bad blocks.